# Why is my MiniMax Implementation not working?

Tags: python, algorithm, minimax

I'm currently working on an unbeatable tic tac toe game in python utilizing the Minimax algorithm. At this point I've been stuck for a few days trying to figure out why the algorithm is not returning the correct score or moves for the AI to play. In the programs current state, if I play the first move (X) in the top left corner, the minimax returns a score of 0, which seems correct as the computer can only tie. This should however apply to all corners, and any initial input on the bottom row returns -1 which is incorrect. The best move that are returned are also infact not the best moves. Any input would be appreciated, hints would be preferred over a full answer. I have included relevant code below:

```
   #executes on odd numbered turns (AI goes second) Currently configured with print statements for debugging
    def AI_Logic():
      score = minimax(Board, False)
      x, y = bestmove
      Board[x][y] = 0
      print(count)
      print(bestmove)
      print(score)
      print(Board)
      Turn += 1

def minimax(Board, Maxplayer):
    global bestmove
    global count

    count += 1
    # Checks if the board is full or if a player has won
    if is_Full(Board) or has_Won(Board) == True:

        # Checks for wins, if no wins exists return 0
        if has_Won(Board) == False:
            return 0

        # If O has won , return 1
        elif who_Won(Board) == 0:
            return 1 

        # If X has won, return -1
        elif who_Won(Board) == 1:
            return -1 

    if Maxplayer == True:
        maxscore = float("-inf")
        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                if Board[x][y] == None:
                    Board[x][y] = 0
                    score = minimax(Board, False)
                    Board[x][y] = None
                    if score > maxscore:
                        bestmove = (x, y)
                    maxscore = max(maxscore, score)

        return maxscore

    else:
        minscore = float("inf")
        for x in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                if Board[x][y] == None:
                    Board[x][y] = 1
                    score = minimax(Board, True)
                    Board[x][y] = None
                    minscore = min(minscore, score)

        return minscore


def is_Full(Board):
    if any(None in sublist for sublist in Board):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def who_Won(Board):
    global hasWon
    # Checks for three of a kind in first column
    if Board[0][0] == Board[1][0] and Board[0][0] != None:
        if Board[1][0] == Board[2][0]:
            hasWon = 1
            return Board[2][0]
    if Board[0][0] == Board[0][1] and Board[0][0] != None:
        if Board[0][1] == Board[0][2]:
            hasWon = 1
            return Board[0][2]
    # Checks for diag win top Left to bottom right
    if Board[0][0] == Board[1][1] and Board[0][0] != None:
        if Board[1][1] == Board[2][2]:
            hasWon = 1
            return Board[2][2]
    # Checks for diag win bottom left to top right
    if Board[0][2] == Board[1][1] and Board[0][2] != None:
        if Board[1][1] == Board[2][0]:
            hasWon = 1
            return Board[2][0]
    # Checks for center column win
    if Board[0][1] == Board[1][1] and Board[0][1] != None:
        if Board[1][1] == Board[2][1]:
            hasWon = 1
            return Board[2][1]
    # Checks for right column win:
    if Board[0][2] == Board[1][2] and Board[0][2] != None:
        if Board[1][2] == Board[2][2]:
            hasWon = 1
            return Board[2][2]
    # Checks for second row win:
    if Board[1][0] == Board[1][1] and Board[1][0] != None:
        if Board[1][1] == Board[1][2]:
            hasWon = 1
            return Board[1][2]
    # Checks for third row win:
    if Board[2][0] == Board[2][1] and Board[2][0] != None:
        if Board[2][1] == Board[2][2]:
            hasWon = 1
            return Board[2][2]


def has_Won(Board):

    # Checks for three of a kind in first column
    if Board[0][0] == Board[1][0] and Board[0][0] != None:
        if Board[1][0] == Board[2][0]:
            return True
    if Board[0][0] == Board[0][1] and Board[0][0] != None:
        if Board[0][1] == Board[0][2]:
            return True
    # Checks for diag win top Left to bottom right
    if Board[0][0] == Board[1][1] and Board[0][0] != None:
        if Board[1][1] == Board[2][2]:
            return True
    # Checks for diag win bottom left to top right
    if Board[0][2] == Board[1][1] and Board[0][2] != None:
        if Board[1][1] == Board[2][0]:
            return True
    # Checks for center column win
    if Board[0][1] == Board[1][1] and Board[0][1] != None:
        if Board[1][1] == Board[2][1]:
            return True
    # Checks for right column win:
    if Board[0][2] == Board[1][2] and Board[0][2] != None:
        if Board[1][2] == Board[2][2]:
            return True
    # Checks for second row win:
    if Board[1][0] == Board[1][1] and Board[1][0] != None:
        if Board[1][1] == Board[1][2]:
            return True
    # Checks for third row win:
    if Board[2][0] == Board[2][1] and Board[2][0] != None:
        if Board[2][1] == Board[2][2]:
            return True

    return False

# Checks the position of a mouse click and draws an X/O, Appends the Board matrix with a 1 in the correct spot to reflect an X, 0 to relfect O
def draw_X(x, y):
    global Turn
    # Checks if turn is an even number (i.e x's turn)
    if Turn % 2 == 0:
        # Series of statements checking the x and y pos of the mouse. Each mouse click lies in a specific box, draw the X/O in the center of the box,
        # making sure there is nothing in the box, and not to overwrite if an X or O already exist.
        if x < WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[0][0] == None:
                Board[0][0] = 1
                WIN.blit(X, (60, 60))
                # Increases Turn after each executed x or O drawing
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[0][1] == None:
                Board[0][1] = 1
                WIN.blit(X, (WIDTH / 3 + 60, 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH and y < HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[0][2] == None:
                Board[0][2] = 1
                WIN.blit(X, (WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 + 60, 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT - HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[1][0] == None:
                Board[1][0] = 1
                WIN.blit(X, (60, HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT - HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[1][1] == None:
                Board[1][1] = 1
                WIN.blit(X, (WIDTH / 3 + 60, HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH and y < HEIGHT - HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[1][2] == None:
                Board[1][2] = 1
                WIN.blit(X, (WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 + 60, HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT:
            if Board[2][0] == None:
                Board[2][0] = 1
                WIN.blit(X, (60, HEIGHT - HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT:
            if Board[2][1] == None:
                Board[2][1] = 1
                WIN.blit(X, (WIDTH / 3 + 60, HEIGHT - HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH and y < HEIGHT:
            if Board[2][2] == None:
                Board[2][2] = 1
                WIN.blit(X, (WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 + 60, HEIGHT - HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1

    # On odd number turns, O will be drawn onto the board:
    else:

        if x < WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[0][0] == None:
                Board[0][0] = 0
                WIN.blit(O, (60, 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[0][1] == None:
                Board[0][1] = 0
                WIN.blit(O, (WIDTH / 3 + 60, 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH and y < HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[0][2] == None:
                Board[0][2] = 0
                WIN.blit(O, (WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 + 60, 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT - HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[1][0] == None:
                Board[1][0] = 0
                WIN.blit(O, (60, HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT - HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[1][1] == None:
                Board[1][1] = 0
                WIN.blit(O, (WIDTH / 3 + 60, HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH and y < HEIGHT - HEIGHT/3:
            if Board[1][2] == None:
                Board[1][2] = 0
                WIN.blit(O, (WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 + 60, HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT:
            if Board[2][0] == None:
                Board[2][0] = 0
                WIN.blit(O, (60, HEIGHT - HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 and y < HEIGHT:
            if Board[2][1] == None:
                Board[2][1] = 0
                WIN.blit(O, (WIDTH / 3 + 60, HEIGHT - HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1
        elif x < WIDTH and y < HEIGHT:
            if Board[2][2] == None:
                Board[2][2] = 0
                WIN.blit(O, (WIDTH - WIDTH / 3 + 60, HEIGHT - HEIGHT / 3 + 60))
                Turn += 1

# 3x3 Matrix used for game logic
Board = [[None]*3, [None]*3, [None]*3]
# Executes every frame, draws the board, checks for wins, and updates the display
def draw_Window():

    draw_Board()
    has_Won(Board)
    pygame.display.update()
# Main Event Loop
def main():
    global Turn
    FPS = 60
    run = True
    WIN.fill((255, 255, 255))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while run:

        clock.tick(FPS)
        draw_Window()
        # Runs the AI turn on odd numbers
        if Turn % 2 != 0:
            while x:
                AI_Logic()
                x = False
        # Checks for winner
        if has_Won == True:
            pass
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            # Checks if a mouse is clicked. When clicked, it records the x and y pos of the mouse and passes it through the draw_X function
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                draw_X(x, y)
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()


main()
```

Comment: Can we see how you're making the board that you pass into these functions?

Comment: Absolutely, just added more code to the post, player inputs are added through the draw_X function.

Comment: There is a lot of code, and I can't run it, could you put the entire thing on pastebin?

Comment: Have you run your `minimax` function on its own without any UI - e.g. just some basic tests on different boards in a console application or testing framework?

Comment: As requested here is the whole code via paste bin. https://pastebin.com/DjeHMaKD I disabled some aspects that I will reimplement later (e.g actually drawing the ai's turn on the ui) It currently just prints the state of the board after the ai's turn. I will try implementing the same algorithm in a simpler program without a UI to see if I achieve a different result. Good suggestion.

Comment: Only tangentially related: if you want a heuristic that also plays for the quickest win, just multiply the evaluation by the number of spaces that are still empty on the board. That way when there is an immediate win on `2,2`, it won't be ignored in favor of an equally good win that has a longer sequence of moves.

Comment: so removing the UI aspect of adding to the the Board did not seem to have an effect on the algorithm.

Comment: Have a look at this answer. It may contain a few ideas to simplify the board manipulation and AI implementation.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493565/5237560