# Tic Tac Toe game using python

Tags: python

1. If you look at line 12 I need to make a restriction so that you can not overlap each other. (for example I don't want "X" to go on a spot where "O" already is. (And yes I have to use a while loop) I have tried different ways but it does not seem to work.

Here is my entire code I have so far that I want to improve:

```
board=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
playerturn="X"

while True:
    for i in range(0,9,3):
        print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")

    choose=int(input("Where do you want to play your" + " " + playerturn + ":"))

    while[Need help making restriction here]
    print("That spot is already occupied")
    choose=int(input("Choose another spot:"))

    board[choose-1]=playerturn
    if playerturn =="X":
        playerturn="O"
    else:
        playerturn="X"

    count=0

    if (board[0]==board[1]) and (board[1]==board[2]):
        for i in range(0,9,3):
            print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")
    winner=board[0]
    print("The winner is", winner)
    break

    elif (board[3]==board[4]) and (board[4]==board[5]):
        for i in range(0,9,3):
            print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")
    winner=board[3]
    print("The winner is", winner)
    break

    elif (board[6]==board[7]) and (board[7]==board[8]):
        for i in range(0,9,3):
            print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")
    winner=board[6]
    print("The winner is", winner)
    break

    elif (board[0]==board[3]) and (board[3]==board[6]):
        for i in range(0,9,3):
            print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")
    winner=board[0]
    print("The winner is", winner)
    break

    elif (board[1]==board[4]) and (board[4]==board[7]):
        for i in range(0,9,3):
            print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")
    winner=board[0]
    print("The winner is", winner)
    break

    elif (board[2]==board[5]) and (board[5]==board[8]):
        for i in range(0,9,3):
            print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")
    winner=board[2]
    print("The winner is", winner)
    break

    elif (board[0]==board[4]) and (board[4]==board[8]):
        for i in range(0,9,3):
            print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")
    winner=board[0]
    print("The winner is", winner)
    break

    elif (board[2]==board[4]) and (board[4]==board[6]):
        for i in range(0,9,3):
            print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
    if (i<6):
        print("------------")
    winner=board[2]
    print("The winner is", winner)
    break

    for item in board:
        if (item != "X") and (item != "O"):
            count +=1

    if count==0:
        for i in range(0,9,3):
            print(board[i], "|", board[i+1], "|", board[i+2])
        if (i<6):
            print("------------")
            print("Tie game")
            break
```

Comment: Your indentation is really messed up. Please repost with correct indentation, because it's impossible to tell what the script is doing.

Comment: What is `while[]` supposed to be? That's invalid syntax.

Comment: I think the `while[]` is just a placeholder, since that seems to be the line they are asking about...

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This suggests a collection of needs that are too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You can look here for ideas on how to approach Tic Tac Toe game: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493565/5237560

Comment: I tried fixing it. Is this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while` loop that checks whether the choice can be played.

```
choose=int(input("Where do you want to play your" + " " + playerturn + ":"))
while board[choose-1] in ('X', 'O'): # These are the values when a spot is occupied
    print("That spot is already occupied")
    choose=int(input("Choose another spot:"))
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: What part of it needs explaining?

Comment: Why did you put it in (X,Y)? What does that do?

Comment: Also I am supposed to have a Boolean expression for this one

Comment: `board[choose-1] in ('X', 'Y')` is a boolean expression.

Comment: `expression in collection` tests whether the value of the expression is an element of the collection. So `in ('X', 'Y')` tests if the board element is either `'X'` or `'Y'`. This is a common Python operator.

Comment: The double `choose=` was just a copying error.

Comment: What other possible values are there? It starts out as 1-9, and when the user plays it does `board[choose-1]=playerturn`. The only values of `playerturn` are `X` and `Y`. So if it has X or Y then that spot is occupied, otherwise it's unoccupied.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a mistake