# Making tic tac toe using 2d numpy array and dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am making a game of Tic Tac Toe using a 2-d Numpy array and want it to be in a way that I can convert the input taken from user into the correct matrix position using dictionaries but am getting this error:

```
movesDict = {1:[[0][0]], 2:[[0][1]], 3:[[0][2]], 4:[[1][0]], 5:[[1][1]], 6:[[1][2]], 7:[[2][0]], 8:[[2][1]], 9:[[2][2]]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Example user gave the number 1 and it gets converted into the matrix position [0][0] and their turn is placed there

```
move = input("Move to which place {}?".format(turn))
realMove = movesDict[move]
```

Comment: You don't need a dictionary.  `divmod(move-1,3)` will give you the coordinates.  But using a matrix for tic-tac-toe is overly complex.  See here for a simpler approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61493565/5237560

Answer (score 1):

The keys in your dictionary are integers, the input from the user is a string.

You need to convert the user input to an integer and you might want to check for invalid inputs.

```
move = input("Move to which place {}?".format(turn))
realMove = movesDict.get(int(move), 'Invalid Move')
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I realised the problem was that I forgot to put commas between the elements in the dictionary. The correct code is:

```
movesDict = {1:[[0],[0]], 2:[[0],[1]], 3:[[0],[2]], 4:[[1],[0]], 5:[[1],[1]], 6:[[1],[2]], 7:[[2],[0]], 8:[[2],[1]], 9:[[2],[2]]}
```